# How To find properietry beacons using Alt beacon android lib

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, beacon, altbeacon

I know by docs that to find a properietry beacon we have to add that beacon's parser to beacon manager.like this:

beaconManager.beaconParsers.add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"))

But here I don't know which type of beacon that I have wheather it is iBeacon or EddyStone so I don't know which parser to add so I added all the parsers that are available in the library and which I can find in the internet.The problems are:

1. I am only detecting one beacon every time.
2. I am unable to detect my beacon

But the app RFS connect is showing multiple beacons and it is also showing my beacon too. So how does that app developer know my beacon's layout ?

And the app Beacon scope which davidgyoung (lead engineer of the alt beacon library) suggested is also not showing my beacon.

So If i have to define the parser my my beacon how can I find it and how the RFS connect app is able to detect my beacon.

Comment: Perhaps you can share a screenshot of what you see on the "RFS Connect" app.  Perhaps you mean the same thing, but there is also a Nordic NRF Connect app, which scans all kinds of Bluetooth devices, even those that are not beacons.